# How to summarize table in R, according to each ID

Tags: r, aggregate

So I have a table structured like this

```
id   V1    V2
101, 500,   1
101, 600,   1
102, 300,   0
102, 300,   0
102, 400,   0
102, 100,   1
103, 200,   0
103, 400,   0
104, 200,   1
```

And basically for each id, I want to calculate the mean of V1, and the sum of V2, so the new table should look like this

```
id   V1    V2
101, 550,  2
102, 275,  1
103, 400,  0
104, 200,  1
```

If anyone can help out I'd really appreciate that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use one of the aggregating functions for this kind of problems.  Here, I use `dplyr`.  We `group_by` 'id' and `summarise` the 'V1' and 'V2' columns with `mean` and `sum` of those corresponding columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(V1=mean(V1, na.rm=TRUE), V2= sum(V2, na.rm=TRUE))
#   id  V1 V2
#1 101 550  2
#2 102 275  1
#3 103 300  0
#4 104 200  1
```

Or another option is `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'id', we get the `mean` and `sum` of the columns.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(V1=mean(V1, na.rm=TRUE), V2= sum(V2, na.rm=TRUE)), by = id]
#    id  V1 V2
#1: 101 550  2
#2: 102 275  1
#3: 103 300  0
#4: 104 200  1
```

Or using `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, by(df1, df1[1], FUN=function(x) 
      data.frame(id=x[1,1], V1= mean(x[,2], na.rm=TRUE), 
                            V2=sum(x[,3], na.rm=TRUE))))
```

Comment: thank you so much. I used dplyr and it worked for sum, but not for mean of V2. For response I'm getting all NA. Do you think it might have to do with the fact that for V2 for each id, it contains at least an NA? is there anyway I can calculate the mean while ignoring the na? should V2= mean(na.omit(V2)) work?

Comment: @KenLam There are options in `mean` and `sum` to remove NA values. ie. `mean(V1, na.rm=TRUE)` and `sum(V2, na.rm=TRUE)`, just replace the code with this and it should work.  Similarly for the `data.table` and `base R` solutions

Comment: @KenLam If you get a doubt with a function, it is always useful to check the help page of that function.  For example `?mean` or `?sum` gives the usage of that function along with description and some examples

Comment: thank you so much. I used dplyr and it worked. if I want to check the number of rows for each id, how should I go about it? I tried to do it with nrow(b) but it'd just return the nrow of the original table

Comment: @KenLam For the `dplyr` solution It can be `df1 %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%summarise(n=n())`